# Java inheriting from two classes

Tags: java, puredata

I'm using an interface in java, that communicates with PureData. In order to do so, my classes have to extend a given class `MaxObject`. While designing my class, which is a cirular buffer, I discovered that I need to extend java's `Iterator` class. So I have to extend two classes at the same time.

My guess is that the only solution is to create two different classes and let one of them be a component of the other one. But, is it the only solution? Is it the best one?

Further, whenever I find myself needing inherit from two classes, is it a because of a bad design? Is there a design pattern to solve this class?

Thank you

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to always design APIs with an interface and a default abstract class.  At least you allow the user the ability to use the interface.

Comment: Diesn't sound like a great design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Iterator` is not a class, it's an interface. As such, you don't extend it, you implement it. You can implement any number of interfaces - the only limitation is that you can only extend one class.

In your case:

```
class MyClass extends MaxObject implements Iterator<Type>
```

Answer (score 2):

edit:  I should have read closer what's being extended.  EboMike is right, you don't need to extend the Iterator class.

Sounds like the DDofD: http://javacodeonline.blogspot.com/2009/08/deadly-diamond-of-death.html

Comment: Great explanation of the DDofD, it makes sense. Anyway, what about c++, how is this problem avoided ? or simply it's not?

Comment: Don't do the DDofD in C++. Worst worst case, you can do virtual inheritance, but that's almost always a bad idea. In many cases, you fare better by adding components via "has-a" rather than "is-a". In Java however, implementing several interfaces is perfectly acceptable - that's why Java has the distinction between parent classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator` is an interface. From a theoretical point of view there's nothing against extending MaxObject and implementing `Iterator`.

Due to a lack of information I cannot say if it's a good idea to do this, but I have a bad feeling.

Comment: Me too. Sounds like it should implement `Iterable`, not `Iterator`